# How I can make a http request with Firebase to external APIs?

Tags: node.js, firebase, http-request

I would like to migrate an app Node.js to Firebase. In NodeJS Server was using this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/rq/bots', function (req, res) {
var query='http://externalAPIQuery?q=something'
var request = require('request');
request(query, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        res.json(JSON.parse(body))
      }
    })
})
```

and from client used to use jQuery to call the functions of the server:

```
var parameters = { 'terms' 'term'}
$ .get ( '/ Rq / bots', parameters, function (data) {
         console.log (data);})
```

But Firebase has no management server and do not know how I make external http request.

Can someone help me make an external request with Firebase?

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/NWi1RyEtSqk

Answer (score 3):

> Someone can help me make an external request with firebase.

Maybe it is possible to make an external request from the **front-end client-side** code?

Many APIs have enabled CORS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Alternatively, if CORS is not enabled there some techniques, I'm usually using:

- http://anyorigin.com/
- http://www.whateverorigin.org/

Answer (score 0):

Firebase only host static content, html, css, media and javascript. You can not run a Node.js app.
Firebase has an api for Node.js but is to connect to your Firebase database from your server.